# Script para ver el ranking de las tablas más fragmentadas de una base de datos

Tags: sql, sql-server

Busco realizar un script que me dé como resultado un ranking de las tablas más fragmentadas ya que actualmente solo puedo hacerlo mediante la opción `REBUILD`, pero hay que irlo haciendo manualmente tabla por tabla. Y mi plan es correr un script de esta forma:

```
ALTER INDEX ALL ON avRoomDetail REBUILD;
```

Script aplicable a cada una de las tablas que estén en el TOP de fragmentación.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes de que inicies un proyecto muy ambicioso, te recomiendo que analices proyectos que ya han sido creados y probados durante años. Una de las mejores soluciones para mantenimiento de las bases de datos es el de [Ola Hallengren](https://ola.hallengren.com/). Te recomiendo que te lo tomes en cuenta. Como alternativa, también esta [Minion Reindex](https://www.MinionWare.net) y varias otras opciones que no recuerdo.

Pero respondiendo a la pregunta que realizas, te dejo una consulta que obtiene la fragmentación de tus índices, solo habría que modificarla para reducir los resultados según lo que necesites.

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(i.object_id) AS tabla,
       i.name AS indice,
       MAX(avg_fragmentation_in_percent) AS Maxima_fragmentacion,
       SUM(page_count) AS paginas
FROM sys.indexes i
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(), i.object_id, i.index_id, NULL, 'LIMITED') s 
WHERE alloc_unit_type_desc = 'IN_ROW_DATA' 
AND index_level = 0
GROUP BY i.object_id, 
         i.index_id, 
         i.name
ORDER BY maxima_fragmentacion DESC;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias tomaré en cuenta las soluciones que me mencionaste

Answer (score 0):

Te muestro una solución a lo que indicas haciendo uso de la respuesta anterior, la cual me ha resultado muy útil.

```sql
DECLARE @DatabaseName NVARCHAR(255);
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(255);
DECLARE @IndexName NVARCHAR(255);
DECLARE @Fragmentation DECIMAL(18,2);

DECLARE IndexCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT 
        DB_NAME(s.database_id) as DatabaseName,
        OBJECT_NAME(i.object_id) AS TableName,
               i.name AS indice,
               MAX(avg_fragmentation_in_percent) AS Maxima_fragmentacion
        FROM sys.indexes i
        CROSS APPLY sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(), i.object_id, i.index_id, NULL, 'LIMITED') s 
        WHERE alloc_unit_type_desc = 'IN_ROW_DATA' 
        AND index_level = 0
        GROUP BY 
                s.database_id,
                i.object_id, 
                i.index_id, 
                i.name
        HAVING MAX(avg_fragmentation_in_percent) > 30
        ORDER BY maxima_fragmentacion DESC;

OPEN IndexCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM IndexCursor INTO @DatabaseName, @TableName, @IndexName, @Fragmentation;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @RebuildReorganizeQuery NVARCHAR(MAX);

    IF @Fragmentation >= 5 AND @Fragmentation < 30 -- Reorganizar si la fragmentación es moderada
    BEGIN
        SET @RebuildReorganizeQuery = 'USE  [' + @DatabaseName + ']; ALTER INDEX [' + @IndexName + '] ON [' + @TableName + '] REORGANIZE';
    END
    ELSE -- Reconstruir si la fragmentación es significativa
    BEGIN
        SET @RebuildReorganizeQuery = 'USE  [' + @DatabaseName + ']; ALTER INDEX [' + @IndexName + '] ON [' + @TableName + '] REBUILD';
    END

    BEGIN TRY
        PRINT 'Ejecutando: ' + @RebuildReorganizeQuery;
        EXEC sp_executesql @RebuildReorganizeQuery;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT 
            ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
            ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage,
            ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
            ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState;
    END CATCH

    FETCH NEXT FROM IndexCursor INTO @DatabaseName, @TableName, @IndexName, @Fragmentation;
END

CLOSE IndexCursor;
DEALLOCATE IndexCursor;
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer].